# XPS 13 9350 - Audio produces nothing but hissing/white noise

Tags: audio

Fresh install on the XPS, ElementaryOS only, no Windows. If I try and play music I just get white noise. If I alter any of the volume knobs a blip of white noise plays after (I assume this is down to  sound that would play after adjusting). Essentially any noise is replaced by white noise!

Comment: Does this happen with speakers, headphones, or both?

Comment: Speakers produce white noise, headphones produce no sound at all by the looks of it!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this exact same issue, I just performed a BIOS update on my XPS 13 which completely fixed the issue.